# How to embed field with entity inheritance in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

If I have two classes extenting an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private String model;
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int seatingCapacity;
    private double topSpeed;
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    private double payloadCapacity;
}
```

I would like to serialize data in JSON using jackson (and spring-boot).
By default JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {"model": "vw", "type": "car", "seatingCapacity": 5, ...},
    {"model": "volvo", "type": "truck", "payloadCapacity": 10, ...},
    ...
]
```

But for the API, I need that specific fields for each subclass to be include into the class type.

```
[
    {
     "model": "vw", 
     "type": "car", 
     "car": {"seatingCapacity": 5, ...}
    },
    {
     "model": "volvo", 
     "type": "truck", 
     "truck": {"payloadCapacity": 10, ...}
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: A workaround would be to add a `@JsonProperty` with a path on each fied in subclasses. Something like: `@JsonProperty (value = "car.seatingCapacity")`. But it generate "car.seatingCapacity" key instead of "car": {"seatingCapacity": n}

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange case because your default JSON actually represents the vehicles as you have defined them. I would say the easiest way would be if these objects are used only to represent the responses that are send to modify the classes to something like:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
   CarProperties car=new CarProperties();

   class CarProperties {
      private int seatingCapacity;
      private double topSpeed;
   }
}
```

This might not be very cool looking but it will represent the json you want. Also if you don't have code in Vehicle class but just define property maybe you can substitute it with an interface with one getModel() method.

Another solution would be to write custom Jackson serializer but it will make the code much more complicated and will couple the objects with it. Or of course you can generate your own json from these properties using some JsonObject class and adding the properties manually.

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson it is possible to create custom deserializers if necessary. If you have the possibility to create a structure which is the same with truck and car, I would try that first as it is easier to implement. But otherwise you can create something like:

```
public class VehicleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Vehicle> { 

    @Override
    public Vehicle deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        String vehicleType = node.get("type").asText();

        if (vehicleType.equals("car")) {
            // Values should be loaded through node
            return new Car();
        }

        if (vehicleType.equals("truck")) {
            // Values should be loaded through node
            return new Truck();
        }

        // Return default or exception if not recognized
    }
}
```

And `ObjectMapper` has to be updated:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Vehicle.class, new VehicleDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```